# RichFaces Data Table Quirk

Tags: jsf, richfaces

With RichFaces you can create a data table like this:

```xml
<rich:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBean.values}" var="value">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column />
            <rich:column>Value 1</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Value 2</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Value 3</rich:column>
            <rich:column>Value 4</rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </f:facet>

    <rich:column />
    <rich:column>#{value.val1}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{value.val2}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{value.val3}</rich:column>
    <rich:column>#{value.val4}</rich:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column>TOTALS</rich:column>
            <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal1}</rich:column>
            <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal2}</rich:column>
            <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal3}</rich:column>
            <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal4}</rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

This generates a basic HTML `<table>` with five columns, a header, and a footer.

However, if you do this instead (the `<rich:dataTable>` is exactly the same):

```xml
<div id="myTableHeader"></div>
<div id="myTableBody">
    <rich:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBean.values}" var="value">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <rich:columnGroup>
                <rich:column />
                <rich:column>Value 1</rich:column>
                <rich:column>Value 2</rich:column>
                <rich:column>Value 3</rich:column>
                <rich:column>Value 4</rich:column>
            </rich:columnGroup>
        </f:facet>

        <rich:column />
        <rich:column>#{value.val1}</rich:column>
        <rich:column>#{value.val2}</rich:column>
        <rich:column>#{value.val3}</rich:column>
        <rich:column>#{value.val4}</rich:column>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <rich:columnGroup>
                <rich:column>TOTALS</rich:column>
                <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal1}</rich:column>
                <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal2}</rich:column>
                <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal3}</rich:column>
                <rich:column>#{myBean.totalVal4}</rich:column>
            </rich:columnGroup>
        </f:facet>
    </rich:dataTable>
</div>
<div id="myTableFooter"></div>
```

RichFaces will place the `<thead>` inside the "myTableHeader" `<div>` and the `<tfoot>` inside the "myTableFooter" `<div>`, with the `<tbody>` remaining inside the `<table>` in the "myTableBody" `<div>`. RichFaces sets the width of every cell so that the columns still line up. Note that the ID's of these elements are important - they must start with the ID of the table element and end with these specific suffixes. The `<table>` actually contains a `display:none` copy of the header as well, and an empty footer.

I only know this works because I found it in some of our code, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this feature. **Is this feature documented anywhere?** I don't really know what the rules are for it.

Comment: I copied your code and I see NO QUIRKS. You state nothing about your environment, maybe RichFaces version here is _not_ important.

Comment: We've used RichFaces 4.3.6 and 4.5.17 on WebSphere 8.5.5.X.

Comment: Great. I use 4.5.17 + Tomcat and as I said: everything is normal. No "quirk". So you have to create [mcve] or check your app more closely. You can check RF code itself (I don't think there is anything which can lead to your problem).